# How to keep the ethernet card up when shutting down Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shutdown, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to get Wake On Lan working on my old machine, all is configured but when I shutdown my PC, I can't keep the ethernet card awake.

It's not a problem with the bios.
It's not a network problem.
My network card is compatible.
The magic packet is well received ("netstat -ntp").

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it's not a programming question. Try asking at e.g. http://askubuntu.com

Comment: see this http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/49807-63-ethernet-card-power-computer

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think WOL is only effective if you suspend your system, not if you shut it down...

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is :"Can't wake PC over Internet after turn off PC a long  time about 20 minutes", your should research MAC binding feature on router